# Doctrine: can't assign aliases to subqueries

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, alias

I have a doctrine query that has a subquery in the select in order to get a field out of another table (and get rid of a heavy left join).

The thing is that the alias that Doctrine is returning me are not what I would like them to be, and therefore I'd love to customize them. Is this possible?

Here's my query:

```
$query->select(
        "id, page_id, status, title, "
      . "segment, url, current_user_id, "
      . "current_user_last_action_time, pt.name,"
    )
        ->addSelect("(SELECT s.username from sfGuardUser s where id = current_user_id) ")
        ->innerJoin( 'PbType pt' )
        ->innerJoin( 'LatestVersion lv WITH version=lv.version' )
        ->where('is_visible = 1')
        ->groupBy( 'page_id' );
```

This is returning me a query like this:

```
SELECT `p`.`id` AS `p__id`, `p`.`page_id` AS `p__page_id`, 
`p`.`status` AS `p__status`, `p`.`title` AS `p__title`, `p`.`segment` AS `p__segment`,
 `p`.`url` AS `p__url`, `p`.`current_user_id` AS `p__current_user_id`, 
`p`.`current_user_last_action_time` AS `p__current_user_last_action_time`, 
`p2`.`id` AS `p2__id`, `p2`.`name` AS `p2__name`, 
(SELECT `s`.`username` AS `s__username` FROM `sfguard`.`sf_guard_user` `s` WHERE 
`p`.`id` = `p`.`current_user_id`) AS `p__0` 
FROM `personaltable`.`page` `p` INNER JOIN `personaltable`.`type` `p2` ON `p`.`type_id` = `p2`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `personaltable`.`latest_page_version` `p3` ON `p`.`page_id` = `p3`.`page_id` 
AND `p`.`version` = `p3`.`version` WHERE `p`.`is_visible` = 1 
GROUP BY `p`.`page_id`
```

It's that  **AS `p__0`** what I want to change. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It should be as easy as

```
->addSelect("(SELECT s.username from sfGuardUser s where id = current_user_id) AS alias")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried that and didn't work. It does assign an alias if I do ->getDql() but not if it's ->getSql().

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time ago an just found one solution which works, but doesn't use the orm.
Try it by using real mysql through your current doctrine connection like this.

```
$query = 'SELECT p.id, p.page_id, p.status, p.title, p.segment, p.url, p.current_user_id,
                 p.current_user_last_action_time, p2.name, 
         ( SELECT s.username from sfGuardUser s where id = p.current_user_id ) as XXX
         FROM personaltable.page p 
         INNER JOIN personaltable.type p2 ON p.type_id = p2.id 
         INNER JOIN personaltable.latest_page_version p3 ON p.page_id = p3.page_id AND p.version = p3.version 
         WHERE p.is_visible = 1 
         GROUP BY p.page_id';


$connection = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$statement = $connection->execute($query)->fetchAll();

foreach ($statement as $key => $val) {
    $id = $statement[$key]['XXX'];
}
```

The XXX is the alias you wan't to customize.

I know that this isn't good style but I wasn't able to do it in any other way.